# Google Directions - different behaviour on different ISPs

Tags: javascript, google-maps

we are using google maps service to fetch directions data between two points in dragdir format:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=43.2602841679131,16.6526985168457&daddr=43.5602841679131,16.7526985168457&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=dragdir
```

Issue we uncounted, manifests in a way that direction path for user connected to internet via particular ISP (ieg. t-com) is drawn or scaled or rotated or translated or with any combination of it.

Also, we use same pattern in android native apps and we had never bumped in such problems.

Do you maybe have any suggestion or good practice how avoid described problems?

Here is sample of dragdir json object returned from maps api:

```
{tooltipHtml:" 
    (151\x26#160;km / 1 hour 51 mins)",polylines:[{id:"route0",points:"e}ruGis|eBsGdPiBxJ{Ab
    h@aAdKoDjNeDlHuC~Di@bBsAnPqAlGwDpGmDbCkGrO
aCzJ.. more scrambled data here ..?B",numLevels:4,zoomFactor:16}]}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe google is making region specific changes to the output.

I would suggest you to direct a call to your server and then call the google service from your server to get an uniform result.

See if you can also mention region in the google service calll itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is being accessed from different parts of the world, it can very well cause the directions to be different. From the [**Region Biasing for Directions** section of the Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TravelModes):

> The Google Maps API Directions Service returns address results
>   influenced by the domain (region or country) from which you loaded the
>   JavaScript bootstrap. (Since most users load http://maps.google.com/
>   this sets an implicit domain to the United States.) If you load the
>   bootstrap from a different supported domain, you will get results
>   influenced by that domain. For example, searches for "San Francisco"
>   may return different results from applications loading
>   http://maps.google.com/ (the United States) than one loading
>   http://maps.google.es/ (Spain).

You can force **Region Biasing** by adding the following to your request URL parameters:

```
[after sensor=false, etc.] &region=US
```

This will set the Directions service to return results biased to a particular region (the USA in this case).